# Powershell how to replace multiple commands with output of single variable

Tags: powershell, scripting

I am traversing an object and would like to replace several path parts with a string stored in another variable. For example:

```
# a is a complex ps object, the path is valid
$a.b.c 
myvalue

$replace = "b.c"
$a.$($replace)
# here I expect 'myvalue', however nothing is returned, as I would like to execute the equivalent of $a.b.c
```

Is there some way to do this replacement?

Comment: hope the linked answers helps